# mongodb querying logic mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I apologize beforehand if this is a repeat question but i could not find any and i am a beginner.

I am making a filter for documents of db.

lets say I want to query 8 fields of documents written in a object

```
filter={key1:{lowerlimit: 'value', upperlimit:'value'},
key2:{lowerlimit: 'value', upperlimit:'value'},
key3:{lowerlimit: '', upperlimit:'value'},
key4:{lowerlimit: 'value', upperlimit:''},
key5:[],
key6:['value','value'],
key7:['value','value','value'],
key8:['value']}
```

now how do i write the logic of query so that  the fields whose value is not specified will not get query. if i query all the parameters as they are. no documents will be displayed because 'key5' is empty array and using $in on it will  result in no documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to remove the `key5` field from your query object when it's empty.

```
if (!filter.key5.length) {
    delete filter.key5;
}
```